# I am trying to create a Google Sheet where on selecting Error in Column N a email should be triggered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Current code send email on editing the cell with any value. What I want is to get the code executed only if the value is Error.

I tried if(cell.value=="error") but it does not work. Please help

Here is my code:

```js
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var emailAddress = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();    
  var project = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();  
  var customer = sheet.getRange('O'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();      
  var task = sheet.getRange('U'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();      
  var status = sheet.getRange('C'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();         
  var mysubject = 'Attention:'+ status + ' Error marked for Case Id' + project ;
  var mybody = '\nHi  ' + status +','+ '\n\nYour Case Number  ' + project + ' has an Error.'+'\nThe QA  ' + customer + ' has marked an error for the case. You are requested to review the case and rectify the error. The details of the error are as below'+'\n\nQA Comments: ' + task + '\n\n\Thank You,'+'\n\nTeam Queue Management';
  if(cell.indexOf('N')!=-1){ 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, mysubject, mybody);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 if(cell.indexOf('N')!=-1)
```

to

```
 if(cellvalue=="error")
```